# Amazon SES configuration set does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

i have a strange error with ConfigurationSetDoesNotExist.

```
Configuration set ... does not exist. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConfigurationSetDoesNotExist;
```

However i set my policies to be fully allowed on ses.

```
  "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:"
            ],
            "Resource": ""
        }
```

Should I allow it on something more? If yes, what is it and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your policy is not correct. You miss a couple '*' in order to allow full access:

```
"Statement": [
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "ses:*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

See [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html).

Hope it helps!